# Не понимаю логику работы сервиса

Tags: angular

Есть компонент начальной страницы, есть сервис к которому идет обращение при каждой загрузке стартовой страницы, который выдает IP пользователя. Проблема - если страницу перегрузить или зайти в первый раз, то IP undefined. Если перейти на любой другой компонент сайта и вернутся на стартовую, то все работает. Вот и вопрос - что я не понимаю и делаю не верно?

Компонент -

```
export class StartPageComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.authService.userSpy().subscribe();
    }
}
```

Сервис -

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    ipAddress: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getUserIP();
    }

    userSpy() {
        const userIPOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({userIP: `${ this.ipAddress }`})
        };
        return this.http.post(environment.apiAuthUrl + Constants.USER_URL, {}, userIPOptions);
    }

    getUserIP() {
        return this.http.get('https://jsonip.com/').subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.ipAddress = res.ip;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в непонимании работы асинхронных методов. Запрос на бек отправлялся до получения данных о IP пользователя. Решил проблему создав сервис, который независимо получает данные об IP и записывает в sessionStorage:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserIpService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.getUserIP();
    }

    getUserIP() {
          this.http.get('https://jsonip.com/').subscribe((res: any) => {
              sessionStorage.setItem('userIP', JSON.stringify(res.ip));
         });
    }
}
```

А уже после этого использую этот сервис в компонентах c таймаутом.